# Stat analysis of seasons duration

Tags: time-series, observational-study

Firstly, how we can define *seasons* - Winter, Spring, Summer and Autumn?
There are many possibilities, let's choose average twenty-four hours temperature $\bar t$.
Next we set $t_1$ and $t_2$   (usually  $0^\circ C$  and $6^\circ C$).
Some  meteorologists define the  winter as period when $\bar{t} <  t_1$ *steadily (stably)*.
So the summer is period, when $\bar{t} >  t_2$ stably.
Between $t_1$ and $t_2$ are placed *transitional time* 
 (for my purposes no matter spring or fall).

There is hypothesis that in Central Europe (and in most of Russia) 
*transitional seasons will be shorter and shorter in the future.*
Well meteorology is a weird science for me so let's use analytical statistics!
With Wolfram Mathematica it's possible to get a lot of weather data. 
Here is example of the analysis: for Moscow 1994-95 (and zoomed period Feb-Jun'94)

[image]
[image]

And here is the question: *how to find duration of  transitional seasons correctly enough?*

Days with $t_1 < \bar{t} < t_2$ painted green. But duration of all green days is not correct solution, 
because many of them are thaws and frosts, not transition!

So I am trying to find an algorithmic definition of transitional seasons duration.

Comment: You need to rigidly define the hypothesis before trying to answer it. As it stands you have a hypothesis relating to 'transitional seasons', but then when you attempt to answer that you find the way you've define that to be imprecise. You now want to find a suitable way to define transition, after looking at the data. Stop. Any analysis you subsequently do is worthless, since you can now (consciously or not) tweak your post hoc definition of 'transitional season' to either support or refute the hypothesis. There is already enough climate pseudo-science that does this. Please don't add to it.

Comment: Why don't just define seasons as they are [standardly defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season#Timing), using solstices and equinoxes? That is (for the Northern emisphere): spring 21 March - 21 June, summer 21 June - 23 September, autumn 23 September - 21 December, winter 21 December - 21 March.

Comment: @nico:  Because the standard definitions don't allow lesobrod to test their hypothesis about season lengths changing.  What they are missing is some clear and reliable criteria as to what will mark the start and end of "stable" and "transitional".  And, albeit with less harsh of a tone than Bogdanovist, that is what I suggest they do before moving forward.  There are many possible ways to define this... and there is probably not a "correctly enough" way to recommend.

Comment: @drknexus: I think it is important to have those. He would have a null hypothesis that the seasons would start and end at those dates, then fix some precise baseline parameters for temperature for each season (e.g. taken from a certain arbitrarily chosen reference period). He can then determine whether there is a deviation from those temperature parameter over the course of the standard seasons. It is clear that the approach shown in the images is very naïve as it does only consider each temperature value and not its neighborood.

Comment: @nico: Yeah, but that approach denies the premise of his question.  Mind you, it might be appropriate to deny, but I prefer to grant people their premises when possible.  Your approach would get him in the ball park of answering his question, but it would be a through a back-door rather than directly addressing his hypothesis of changing "season" duration.  I think it is probably reasonable to try to create a function that generates the temperature shapes he is talking about and then fit that function to the yearly data and compare parameter estimates across years.

Comment: Firstly I'd like define seasons only by average twenty-four hours temperature (to avoid multi-parametrization).  
And it seems I've found (at least one) good criterion.
There is a day, when _t_ become _> t1_ and will become _<t1_ only after several months.
This day wihter ends and spring begins.
The same way (but with _t2_) we can define day when spring ends and summer begins.
This method is well-defined, but I don't like it, 'cause we miss about half of month,
when temperature fastly rise and fall (and this days are sure spring days).

Comment: But, how do you identify t1 and t2, or is that the crux of your question to begin with?  Would you feel comfortable simply expanding the criteria from your cut point to the first previous day in which the temperature moved in the opposite direction of the trend?  E.g. if trying to identify fall, taking all of the previous days of summer where the temperature trend was down from the previous day and categorizing them as fall?

Comment: @drknexus Yes t1 and t2 are free parameters.

Comment: @drknexus:And trend has meaning only in critical days.
If within the summer temperature rises and falls  
(but not less than t2) its no matter.

Comment: I kind of doubt you are going to find t1 and t2 parameters you can estimate that are going to be constant across years and stable enough to reliably give you 4 seasons.  So the next trick is to think about what "stably" at a temperature means to you.  $\bar{t}$ over how many days?

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments"
Yeah good advice =)   
@to all:So I've got good ideas. If someone' interested about this subject, look here tomorrow, here will be some  new results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to answer on my own question.
In fact, main factor for climate is daily average [insolation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insolation)
On 100 km above Earth it's value depends only from latitude and position of day in the year (orange curve). From this point, we *have no any* "stable" seasons, just smooth variations of warm and cold. For convenience, the period with curve above the middle may be "summer", and below -"winter".
Daily average temperature (blue points) is depends on  insolation (but on many others factors too).
In Tashkent  (pic.1)  it is close to insolation curve behavior, but in Lisbon 2001 (pic 2) looks chaotic enough  (all data are rescaled for comparison).
[image: Tashkent climate curve]   [image: Lisbon climate curve]

These pictures suggest me an idea. Let's call “transition“ day when
*daily average temperature crosses year average temperature line.*
In ideal continental climate there should be only two such days in the year.
In oceanic climate every third may be transition day. So I'd like to suggest measure for "seasonality" of the weather. It's just *number of transition days on the year*, divided by 365.
Here are examples of this measure for Khabarovsk and London during last decades:
[image]  [image]
For me it's clear that such measure makes sense, but I can't prove it, using strict stats methods.

And now we can define *what are spring and fall days*, regardless of the phenologist’ assumptions and using only year average temperature.
Let's partition 365 days on samplings by 5-10 days (length of sampling is the only free parameter!) and calculate seasonality measure for every sampling.
Here are another two examples.
[image] [image]

I see spring and fall seasons absolutely clear, regardless of the "vegetations temperature", "hormone level" etc.
Exact duration of transition seasons is dependent from length of sampling (but general qualia stay the same) and this is really statistic question.
That’s all, so I’ll be very glad to see some corrections and opinions.